# Replace shortcodes with html tags notepad++

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

How to search and replace this:

```
[pullquote style="left" quote="dark"]text between[/pullquote]
```

with this:

```
<blockquote>text between</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

Find what: `\[(\w+).*?\]([^\[]+)\[/\1\]`
Replace with: `<blockquote>$2</blockquote>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only problem is when I have other shortcodes that I need to keep in a file like caption images shortcodes that comes by default for every images in WordPress